# default path in expect script condition

Tags: tcl, expect

I'm trying to create an expect script where it will execute every expect condition except the last.

For instance:

```
send -- "command\r"
expect {
        "No such file or directory" {
            
        }
        "Permission Denied" {
            puts "Command Location 1 execution Failed"
        }
        "finished"
    }

send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
exit 0
```

Essentially if the expect script detects "No such file or directory" OR "Permission Denied" I want 'puts "Command Location 1 execution Failed"' to be executed rather than having to duplicate in both conditions. However, if "finished" is detected, I don't want anything to be printed, and just have the exit command be sent.

I was thinking the following:

```
send -- "command\r"
expect {
        "No such file or directory" {
        }
        "Permission Denied" {
        }
        "*" {
         puts "Command Location 1 execution Failed"
        }
        "finished"
    }

send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
exit 0
```

If only I could have a condition where its like !="finished", that would be perfect.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `expect` manual suggests using a regular expression with alternation if you don't want to keep repeating the same action. Something like

```
send -- "command\r"
expect {
        -re "(?i)No such file or directory|Permission Denied" {
            puts "Command Location 1 execution Failed"
        }
        finished
}
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
exit 0
```

Comment: Hi @Shawn , thanks for the solution. The first part is still picked up "No such file" however the "Permission Denied" is not. This is what is being printed:
-bash: path/to/script: Permission denied
It's hanging and is not able to detect the Permission Denied string.

Comment: @Shak Regular expressions are case sensitive.

Comment: REs are case sensitive _by default._ Start them with `(?i)` to make them case-insensitive.

Comment: There's also the `-nocase` option, but I'm not sure if expect applies that to regular expressions or just globs.